# guardar elementos en array por condicion

Tags: reactjs

Tengo dos arreglos arreglo1 y arreglo2, el arreglo1 contiene objetos en el cual los objetos contienen la propiedad edad, el arreglo2 quiero que se llene al filtrar los elementos del arreglo1, al recorrer el arreglo1 quiero llenar el arreglo2 con todos los elementos que la edad que se pasa coincida con el de los objetos del arreglo1, si no se pasa ninguna edad, llenar todo el arreglo2 con todos los elementos del arreglo1. Asi como esta el codigo, ya puedo llenar el arreglo2 con los elementos que coinciden en la edad, pero si paso una edad que no existe o no paso ninguna, quiero llenar el arreglo2 con todos los elementos del arreglo1

```
const arreglo1 = [
  {
    nombre: 'jose',
    ciudad: 'argentina',
    edad: 20
  },
  {
    nombre: 'pedro',
    ciudad: 'brazil',
    edad: 18
  },
  {
    nombre: 'andrea',
    ciudad: 'mexico',
    edad: 20
  },
  {
    nombre: 'luis',
    ciudad: 'eu',
    edad: 19
  },
  {
    nombre: 'nancy',
    ciudad: 'mexico',
    edad: 18
  }
];

const getDatos = (edad) => {
  const arreglo2= arreglo1 .filter(dato => dato.edad === edad);
  
  console.log(resultado)
}

getDatos(20);
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Es lo que hago y guarda los elementos que tienen una edad, pero si no paso nada, no logro hacer que se guarden todos los elementos

Comment: Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si mal no te entiendo solo deberías validar el parámetro edad como parte de la condición del filter, si no está definido se cumple y al estar definido no, por lo que evalúa la segunda condición ya que es un or:

```
const getDatos = (edad) => {
      const arreglo2= arreglo1.filter(dato => ((!edad)|| (dato.edad === edad)));
      console.log(resultado)
}
```